# How to count instances of a unique string in Java or R?

Tags: java, r

I'm trying to count instances of dates in a .txt list, whilst keeping the previous count going, and storing in a HashMap or a TreeMap

For instance if my file begins

- "02/28/2013"
- "02/28/2013"
- "02/28/2013"
- "03/01/2013"
- "03/01/2013"

I'd like the iterator to write

- "02/28/2013" - 3
- "03/01/2013" - 5

I'm trying to do a general accumulation of how many times the dates were recorded whilst keeping the old count. I've tried a buffered reader however I wasn't sure how to keep the old count in the map. Alternatively, I can use R but I'm quite unsure how to record the instances in the same vein as my problem with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `R`, we can do `cumsum` on the frequency count with `table`

```
cumsum(table(v1))
#02/28/2013 03/01/2013 
#       3          5
```

#### data

```
v1 <- rep(c('02/28/2013', '03/01/2013'), c(3,2))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this removed a bunch of other coding that was made unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Another *R* approach is to use run-length encoding

```
> r = rle(v1)
> data.frame(value=r$values, cumlen=cumsum(r$lengths))
       value cumlen
1 02/28/2013      3
2 03/01/2013      5
```

This differs from @akrun's approach when values are not sorted

```
> v2 <- rep(c('02/28/2013', '03/01/2013', '02/28/2013'), c(3, 2, 1))
> as.data.frame(cumsum(table(v2)))
           cumsum(table(v2))
02/28/2013                 4
03/01/2013                 6
> r = rle(v2); data.frame(value=r$values, cumlen=cumsum(r$lengths))
       value cumlen
1 02/28/2013      3
2 03/01/2013      5
3 02/28/2013      6
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate, with a counter, and record result whenever value changes:

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/WScB6I)

```
private static void printRunningCount(String ... input) {
    int count = 0;
    String prev = null;
    for (String value : input) {
        if (! value.equals(prev) || prev == null) {
            if (count != 0)
                System.out.println(prev + " - " + count);
            prev = value;
        }
        count++;
    }
    if (count != 0)
        System.out.println(prev + " - " + count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you can create a Set or Map of words and number of times it has appeared in your file. I am not sure what is with keeping the old count. Your requirement is to keep strings in a Map against number of times that string has appeared ina file. Check if below program helps.

> This is my input file:
>
> abc abc xyz xyz www www aaa aaa zcx zcx aaa abc xyz xyz abc

```
public class NewRepeatedCount  {

    public static void main(String... arg0)
    {
     BufferedReader br = null;
 Map<String, Integer> counterMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    try {

        String sCurrentLine;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = sCurrentLine.split("\\s");
            for(String word : words)
            {
                int count = 1;
                if(counterMap.get(word) != null)
                {
                    count = counterMap.get(word);
                    count++;
                    counterMap.put(word, count);
                }else{
                    counterMap.put(word, count);
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(counterMap.entrySet());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

> Output: [abc=4, aaa=3, www=2, zcx=2, xyz=4]